# Android widget, launch a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-widget, android-xml

I currentley have an adroid widget, that when clicked on launches an activity. I have changed my whole app to fragments in order to use the android navigation drawer, and I am not sure how to launch my fragment when my widget is clicked.

My widget code which launches an activity is:

```
public class SearchWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Search.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_search);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.searchclick, pendingIntent);

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }

    }


}
```

How can I launch a fragment, but also launch it in my view which hold my drawer also?

I have a MainDrawer activity:

```
public class MainDrawer2 extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources


        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0]));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1]));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2]));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3]));



        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());


        //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }


    }



    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new StatisticsPage();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Discover();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Portfolio();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new NewsWeb();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            //case R.id.menu_search2:



                //return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public void goToSearch(MenuItem item){

        //go to search page
        //Intent i = new Intent(this,Search.class);
        //startActivity(i);

        FragmentManager man=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran=man.beginTransaction();
        Fragment Fragment_four= new Search();
        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_four);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }



}
```

The main drawer uses this xml which has a fragment for the navigation drawer and one for the actual fragments that get loaded. The MainDrawer activity above initiates with the statistics fragment. I want my widget to launch with the below xml but not initiate the statistics fragment. I want it to load another fragments.

XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

UPDATE:

```
public class MainDrawer2 extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_DEFAULT_FRAGMENT = "com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro.EXTRA_DEFAULT_FRAGMENT";

    public static final int FRAGMENT_STATISTICS = 0;
    public static final int FRAGMENT_DISCOVER = 1;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources


        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0]));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1]));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2]));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3]));



        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());


        //getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Intent i = getIntent();

            // Default to the stats fragment if a default wasn't supplied
            int defaultView = i.getIntExtra(EXTRA_DEFAULT_FRAGMENT, FRAGMENT_STATISTICS);
            displayView(defaultView);
        }


    }



    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new StatisticsPage();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Discover();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Portfolio();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new NewsWeb();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            //case R.id.menu_search2:



                //return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        //menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    public void goToSearch(MenuItem item){

        //go to search page
        //Intent i = new Intent(this,Search.class);
        //startActivity(i);

        FragmentManager man=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran=man.beginTransaction();
        Fragment Fragment_four= new Search();
        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_four);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }



}
```

Comment: I think you may be a little confused. You absolutely HAVE TO launch an activity in order to have a fragment. Without an Activity, there is no context and Context is extremely important. So in short, inside your activity you try to launch is where you should load the fragment.

Comment: SO I have an activity which is MainDrawer, which has my nav drawer and is where I load my activities. I want to load to a specific fragment that the MainDrawer does not usually default too, when it is loaded. SO do I have to make another whole Drawer activity to load but default to my other fragment? cause then I am pretty much stuck in the other drawer class when accessed from the widget...

Comment: I am not sure i fully understand your question. What do you mean by a drawer ? One that slides from the Left ? Can you provide your code, so I can see what it is you want to do?

Comment: yes, one that slides from the left. I will add more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of doing what you want.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxaaQ-XiIcHAakxVSTZYMURlYm8/

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like you already have a good framework in place that'll make this easy. First, define a value for an extra to pass in with your launch intent:

```
public class MainDrawer2 extends Activity {
    public static final String EXTRA_DEFAULT_FRAGMENT = "my.package.name.EXTRA_DEFAULT_FRAGMENT";

    public static final int FRAGMENT_STATISTICS = 0;
    public static final int FRAGMENT_DISCOVER = 1;
    //... etc.
```

Then, in your onCreate(), where you current call `displayView(0)`, do something like:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Intent i = getIntent();
    // Default to the stats fragment if a default wasn't supplied
    int defaultView = i.getIntExtra(EXTRA_DEFAULT_FRAGMENT, FRAGMENT_STATISTICS);
    displayView(defaultView);
}
```

This way, you can create your `PendingIntent` with your Activity launch `Intent`, but when you do so, simply include the default fragment extra:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainDrawer2.class);
i.putExtra(MainDrawer2.EXTRA_DEFAULT_FRAGMENT, MainDrawer2.FRAGMENT_DISCOVER);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);
```

Comment: trying to see if I am tracking, the if statement is going in the top of my MAinDrawer class in my on create?

Comment: Provided I understand your project structure correctly, then yes. You're basically already defaulting to add the statistics fragment on the first creation of the activity (i.e. when savedInstanceState is null). This just adds a mechanism to intercept that and let you decide via Intent which fragment to display.

Comment: So I added the code and I gegt an erro on the new stuff that say canot resolve method getIntExtra

Comment: Check for typos. `Intent#getIntExtra()` has existed since API 1.

Comment: I fixed it, had to import something. I ust put my updated code in, can you check if I edited it correctly?

Comment: yea, it launched my discover fragment instead of my search. Thinking I have to change a number someplace....

Comment: Please take a look at what you've changed and think about what's actually happening. It should be quite clear why it launched discover instead of search...

Comment: Ok so how I think it works is it changes what is selected in my switch statement. The problem I run into is what I want the widget to open is not displayed in my nav bar...

Comment: after playing with it all night, I am stuck. Not sure what your code is doing, or how its working. Every time I change something it always opens my discover fragment...